# Haxe nodejs split js, insted of one js

Tags: node.js, haxe

How can I generate separated js files, when use Haxe nodejs target?
Now I have one big js file, but I wanted to compile each class to separated js files.
I found modular-js, but if I think good, this is not work for nodejs (because AMD), just for frontend js.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen [**hxgenjs**](https://github.com/kevinresol/hxgenjs)? It claims to support Node.js:

> The default configuration emits one javascript file per Haxe class, and uses CommonJS (require()) to link the dependencies. It **should work out of the box with your current Node.js project**, React Native project or any other CommonJS-compatible runtimes.